# How to disambiguate ADL call with candidates in different namespaces?

Tags: c++, argument-dependent-lookup

Given the following class:

```
struct foo : public boost::static_visitor<> {
    void do_stuff(int item) {}
}
```

Now, in another context I have an `std::vector<foo>` and want to execute the following algorithm on it:

```
using namespace std::tr1;
using namespace std::tr1::placeholders;

std::vector<foo> items;
std::for_each(items.begin(), items.end(), bind(&foo::do_stuff, _1));
```

This throws a huge template error message, that boils down to an ambiguous call to `std::tr1::ref` or `boost::ref`. If I remove the base-class `boost::static_visitor` from `foo` everything works fine.

As far as I understand it, the problem is that deep down in the code of `std::tr1::bind`, a `ref(arg)` is called without namespace qualification. Because `bind` is in the namespace `std::tr1`, `std::tr1::ref` is in scope. But, because `foo` inherits from a class that is in the namespace `boost`, ADL also finds `boost::ref`. Is that understanding correct?

Since I need that base-class (it is part of [Boost.Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/variant.html)), I need to know if tis here any way to disambiguate this call from my code?

Note: I am stuck with C++03 here, hence the use of `std::tr1`.

Comment: I think the [answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20546860/confusion-between-stdtr1ref-and-boostref) is a similar problem, you will need to open up the `boost` or `std::tr1` namespace and provide a special overload it seems.

Answer (score 0):

Jesse has provided a link to an answer that is a solution to this problem. However, in this particular case, I have come up with a different solution. `boost::static_visitor` only has one function, it provides a `result_type` typedef. This can easily be added manually, and the the base-class is not needed anymore.